# Infinite Scrolling on post

Tags: node.js

I need to scroll  blog-posts/latest news infinitely on a browser.
The way it should work is I get first 20 posts from server in a  list. I render first one on browser. After I am close to x height from end of browser - that should load next post from list. While loading next post I need to make a call to analytics, advertisements and also change browser url with new title. Once I reach 20th post, I need to make a call to server to get next 20 posts and this continues.

My question is: what libraries are available to me to make a POC on this?
How do I compare them and which one to choose?

I need to make this project in nodejs and I am new to nodejs. Any available demos might help too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are interested in crunching latest data so this can be achieved by server side pagination, say you'll have to query latest blog-post limited to 20 and also will have to keep track of page-cursor (means from where next query will fetch next 20 blog-posts). You are building in Nodejs so I assume your database to be Mongodb (Assuming [MEAN Stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MEAN)), you can write your own pagination logic but why to re-invent wheel? solutions are available to be used such as [mongoose-paginate](https://github.com/edwardhotchkiss/mongoose-paginate). This completes back-end part.

On front-end there are various plug-ins available for various frameworks such as:

1 - Don't want to use any plugin:

```
$(window).scroll(function () { 
   if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 10) {
      //Add newly-crunched data at the end of the page
   }
});
```

2 - In Angular use [angular-ui pagination](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) or [ngInfiniteScroll](http://binarymuse.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/)

3 - In jQuery use [infinite-scroll](https://github.com/infinite-scroll/infinite-scroll) or [jScroll](http://jscroll.com/)

Here is tuts+ [How to Create Infinite Scroll Pagination](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-infinite-scroll-pagination--wp-24873)

Happy Helping!