# NodeJS - Infinite Scroll

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, scroll, infinite

I've stopped programming in Php a few month ago and began learning nodeJS... and I love it ! But today I need something from Php ( not only ) in my node App, but I can't find it. So, first of all, let's introduce the problem : I've done a website who's referencing all the users's posts on another platform, those are saved in a database in **Mysql**. All those request are easy, but if the user has to much posts, the page loading takes too much time. So what I would like to set up is an 'infinite scrolling' to load the data ( from Mysql ) when the page scrolled twice ( that's a detail ). But it's impossible to find this plug-in in the npm. So... Is there a solution ( **fully nodeJS and Mysql** ) to set up ? Have you ever done anything like this ?

I already thank you for your precious time,
please help me.

EDIT: I don't use AngularJS for the moment, i'm trying with it now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Infinite Scrolling on post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29016668/infinite-scrolling-on-post)

Comment: `and I love it ! But today I need something from Php`  Can you post your PHP stuff as a reference?.  Maybe people could help you convert the PHP code into Node.Js..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the middleware and frontend framework (Angular, React, etc.) your are using with your node application.

I have developed a lot with [Angular](http://angular.io) as frontend framework and used [express](http://expressjs.com/de/) as middleware. This Angular directives does the magic in the frontend:

https://github.com/sroze/ngInfiniteScroll

To use it, you have to provide the "new" data through an API running on your node application:

**(Frontend Framework) --> (Middleware/API) --> (Node app) --> (Database)**

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey ! I've never used Angular, but i've linked my app in node to angular, and it works, i have angular. I could install this plugin but does it only work with front-end ? I have to call a database each 'scrolled page' ;)

Comment: Exactly, you need to call some API/Endpoint to get fresh data each time the user scrolls to the end of the page.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time ! You truly helped me !

Comment: Nice to here that ;)